# Perl hashes with an array of keys

Tags: perl, design-patterns, hashmap

Given an array which contains n elements (n more than 1), is there an elegant way to refer to the element in a hash structure where each element is the key in sequence?

For example:

```
my @foo = ('a','b','z');
```

Given this or something similar, I'd like to access the following:

```
$hash->{'a'}->{'b'}->{'z'}
```

If this was a fixed number of elements it would be simple, but I won't know how many it will be at runtime (certainly never more than 6 or 7, but otherwise unguessable).

The only patterns I can think of all involve loops and references and look clumsy. Is there something that doesn't take up a half a page or require Data::Dumper if you have a typo in it just to debug?

Comment: See [`Data::Diver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Diver) and [`Hash::Flatten`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Flatten)

Comment: @HåkonHægland If you'll turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. Looks like you beat choroba to the punch.

Comment: Thanks, but please accept the answer by Choroba. I am not in competition :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's why [Data::Diver](http://p3rl.org/Data::Diver) exists:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Diver qw{ Dive };

my $hash = { a => { b => { z => 'HERE' } } };

my @foo = qw( a b z );

print Dive($hash, @foo);
```

Comment: Thanks. Thought there must be something, but couldn't figure out a google search that didn't return generic results.

Comment: `Dive($hash, map \$_, @foo)` would be safer (i.e. it would handle numerical keys).